# Send an email if the cell contains the word "expired"

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I would like to use excel to send an email to the email address in column C from C5-C42 when the corresponding cell in column F contains the text "expired". I've been at this for over four days. I appreciate any help I can get.

I also keep getting a run-time error 424.

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("F5:F42"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value = "Expired" Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Your certification has expired." & vbNewLine & _
              "Please contact an admin."

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "emailaddress@net.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = strbody

        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub`... that code looks like it belongs in a `Worksheet_Change` event, not a button click handler. Also, you need to loop over the range `C5-C42`.

Comment: I do not know what that means. I'm sorry.

Comment: See the [`Worksheet.Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event documentation to start.

Comment: OK, I think I understand. Is there anyway to apply this code to a button?

Comment: `Target` does not exist in a button click event.  You are using the wrong code in the wrong event. Also `IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value = "Expired"` will never return `TRUE` as the target cell cannot be both numeric AND the text string `"Expired"`

Comment: You will need to loop the cells `Range("F5:F42")` and check each one for the string desired.

Comment: What if I change the trigger to a numerical trigger like 1 if true and 0 if false?

Comment: Do you only have one button? And you want to click it once and the routine will go through every cell in `Range("F5:F42")` checking for expired?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62160128/mail-a-message-to-each-person-with-an-email-address-in-column-c-and-the-word-ex

Comment: -jamheadart That's exactly what I want to do. And yes only one button.

Comment: I copied your code and made a few amendments, please see the answer below and the comments to at least get you a bit further. By this I mean you've got the right idea and a reasonable structure in place but it could do with a few tweaks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("F5:F42")
    If c.Value2 = "Expired" Then Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook(c.Offset(0, -3).Value2)
Next c
End Sub
```

This first routine is triggered by the command button click. It cycles through each cell in range F5:F42. If the cell has "Expired" as a value, it calls the mail routine, and passes to it the value contained in column C (by using the F column address -3 columns)

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook(emailAddress As String)

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Your certification has expired." & vbNewLine & _
              "Please contact an admin."

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = emailAddress
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = strbody

        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

The mail routine accepts an email address as a parameter and hopefully you'll notice it replaces the generic "email address.com" you had on the `.To` line

**Please be aware** that currently the code is creating a new instance of `Outlook` for every time it needs to send an e-mail, without closing it. I think you can quit Outlook simply with the line `OutApp.Quit` so try sticking that in at the end of the `Mail_small_Text_Outlook` routine

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thank you so much!!!!!!! This is what I've been looking for.

Comment: No problem, any more questions feel free to get stuck in to StackOverflow! It's the best site on the net ;)

Comment: Sorry to bug you again but how do I add multiple buttons?

Comment: A button is an ActiveX control: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-register-an-activex-control-8fc743a1-e72b-4b55-af3a-85d326e53918

Comment: Also if you continue to use StackOverflow, please mark any answers you get as correct if it they solved your issue.